# What is this incomprehensible text about?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

Excuse this question if it sounds a bit wierd, but I have had less than 10 hours of sleep (been primarily studying for exams and at school). Now, while browsing the highest voted questions, I found that [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/how-would-facebook-sysadmins-prevent-the-summoning-of-cthulhu) is strewn with insane combos of characters. Definitely not english. I would show an image of what is happening on my screen, but the image upload is not working properly with Safari on IOS and the hassle of uploading the image to a third party and downloading it to my computer to upload back to Stack Exchange seems a bit tedious. I can do it, though not at this moment, if needed, but I would definitely not want to.

Is that a username? Or something question related? Perhaps a keyboard thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a StackExchange meme about Cthulhu coming over. So the weird characters are made on purpose.

Comment: To be sure, I have seen these before in usernames. Was unsure if it was a hack or something. Thanks.

Comment: I think one of the first - or at least the most popular occurences is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 3):

Say you want a crowned H:

LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H - `&#x48;`: H
WITH COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER T - `&#x36d;`: Hͭ
WITH COMBINING GREEK KORONIS - `&#x343;`:  H̓
WITH COMBINING COMMA ABOVE - `&#x313;`: H̓
WITH COMBINING DOT ABOVE - `&#x307;` Ḣ

Result of all combinations:

`&#x48;&#x36d;&#x343;&#x313;&#x307; ->` Hͭ̓̓̇

Comment: Or you could write a code or find some online tool to do it all for you...

Comment: I use this generator: http://eeemo.net/ Much faster than doing it by hand :)

Answer (score 1):

The characters are turned around and modified by using some UTF-8 control characters, but I'd have to look them up myself to be sure which.

Characters can be way more than only written text.